# Check if pandas column contains all zeros

Tags: pandas

I'm doing a complex calculation on a data frame that is bound to throw exceptions if all the values in a column are zeros. How to do a quick check whether a column is full of zero? i.e. return `True` if the column has values other than `0` else `False`.

Comment: Can you post sample data?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

you can do something like this:

`(df['col'] == 0).all()`

This will return True if all values are 0 otherwise it will return false

Comment: Since you asked for the reverse you can use any()
(df[col] != 0).any()

Comment: Perfect! thank you.

Comment: How to retrieve other columns value /id in case it satisfy `df[col]=0.any()`

Comment: Sorry could not understand your question. Could you please elaborate ?